# Executar comando em Python com Selenium chamado pelo PHP através do Apache

Tags: php, python, apache, selenium-webdriver

Quero executar o seguinte script em Python por um web site no servidor:

```py
#!/Python34/python
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("C:\wamp64\www\desenvol\index.html")
elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("call another page")
elem1.click()
```

O Apache está bem configurado e usei a página com o web site contém o seguinte em php:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Light Controller</title>
    </head>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['LightON']))
        {
            echo exec('python hello.py');
            echo("on");
        }
        if (isset($_POST['LightOFF']))
        {
            shell_exec("sudo python /var/www/lightsoff.py");
            echo("Off");
        }
    ?>

    <form method="post">
        <button name="LightON">Light ON</button>&nbsp;
        <button name="LightOFF">Light OFF</button><br><br>
    </form> 
</html>
```

O que devo fazer?

Comment: Heitor, fiquei sem entender uma coisa, o trecho driver.find_element_by_link_text procura por um link cujo texto é "call another page" mas este texto não existe no html. Me diz uma coisa, o que você quer é disparar o button usando o código em python?

Comment: Qual o problema? O que devo fazer está muito subjetivo. Olhando apenas o codigo imagino que o script `hello.py` não está sendo executado (Provavelmente por não estar no mesmo diretorio).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Eu não resolvi meu problema de uma maneira fácil, então o que fiz foi:

- Primeiro criei uma database com uma tabela com duas colunas(id e numero).
- Então fiz um loop em python para pegar o valor de 'numero' em um id (0) especifico e comparar se esse valor mudou, se isto acontecer o pytho vai executar o web driver command.
- Finalmente, fiz um script php, dentro de uma página html, para atualizar este valor naquele id (0) especifico.

Este é meu código...

### The python final code:

```js
#!/Python34/python  
#from __future__ import print_function #NAO NECESSARIO Estava No exemplo do PyMySQL,aparentemente nao necessario
import time #Importa a função do delay
import pymysql #importa biblioteca para conexao com o python
from selenium import webdriver #biblioteca que me permite acessar o navegador 
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='samsung', db='tccdia')#string de conexao com o MySQL
status = 1 #defina essa variavel para funcionar como uma chave que impede a execução do webdriver assim que o script iniciar 
ValorReferencia = 1 #valor para verificar se o valor do DB foi altera
#chave = 0 #NAO NECESSARIO
while 1<2:
 cur = conn.cursor()
 cur.execute("SELECT numero FROM cw_lampada WHERE id = 0")
 result = cur.fetchone()#criei uma variavel para armazenar esse valor porque ele apaga 
 ValorAtual = result
 ValorAtual = ValorAtual[-1] # Tira aspas e virgulas Funcionou mas nao entendi o procedimento
 print ("valor atual: ",ValorAtual," tipo: " ,type(ValorAtual))  
 if status == 1:
     ValorReferencia = ValorAtual
     status = 0
     #chave=1 #NAO NECESSARIO
 print ("valor referencia: ",ValorReferencia," tipo: " ,type(ValorReferencia))     
 #if chave ==1: ##NAO NECESSARIO Maybe this if ins't necessary
 if ValorAtual != ValorReferencia :
  driver=webdriver.Firefox() #Abre o navegador em determinado endereco e abre link
  driver.get("C:\wamp64\www\desenvol\index.html")
  elem1 = driver.find_element_by_link_text("call another page")
  elem1.click()
  driver.close()
  status = 1
  #chave = 0 #NAO NECESSARIO
 cur.close()
 time.sleep(2) #tempo de espera 
#conn.close() #NAO NECESSARIO nao faria sentido ficar abrindo e fechando conexao se o tempo de reconexao eh curto
```

### The MySQL database was something like:

```css
create database tccdia;
use tccdia;
create table cw_lampada(
  id int primary key,
  numero int
);
```

### And the HTML was:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>lampada</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  require 'config.php';
  require 'connection.php'; #connection deve ser chamado anetes do database
  require 'database.php'; 
 ?>
<form action="" method="post">
         <input type="submit" value="Clicar" name="botao" style="width: 900px; height: 200px;">
    </form>

 <?php
    if(isset($_POST["botao"])){
         echo "botão foi clicado";
   $numero = $numero+1;
     
   $atualizar = array(
    'numero' => $numero
   );                  
  DBUpdate('lampada', $atualizar, 'id=0'); 
    ?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Com certeza existem maneiras mais fáceis e diretas para resolver isto mas foi o que fiz. Espero que essa solução ajude outros com o mesmo problema.

Comment: Poderia traduzir a resposta para o português?

Answer (score -1):

Algumas considerações antes de seguirmos em frente:

- Se o script é em Python por que toda a página não é já em Python?
- Se a pagina é em PHP por que então o script não é em PHP?

Porém, com os anos de experiência aprendemos a lidar com o ambiente do cliente e nem sempre o mesmo vem de uma arquitetura perfeita ou que faça sentido, então vamos seguir em frente com o seu cenário.

No PHP [tem uma função chama shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php). Ou seja maior parte do seu caminho está andado.

Exemplo de execução:

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

No seu script em Python coloca a seguinte no inicio:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Depois desse ajuste no script faça–o ser executavel em plataformas linux:

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

Pronto.